# How to pass data between view controllers in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to pass some data between my first and second `ViewController`. 
I already instantiated the second view controller like this:

```
RegistrationViewController registration = new RegistrationViewController();
```

I set the value of the textfield to the variable email from the registration class like this:

```
registration.email = txtEmail.Text; 
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(registration, true);
```

Then in the second `ViewController` I use it like this:

```
public string email { get; set; }
txtEmail.Text = email ;
```

Sadly, I don't have a value in the email variable. How can I achieve successfully passing the data to the new `ViewController`.

Code for changing the controller:

```
 registration.email = txtEmail.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    RegistrationViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("RegistrationViewController") as RegistrationViewController;

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(registration, true);
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
```

Comment: VC's are just C# classes.  You can pass data using public properties, constructors, public methods, etc.  What you're doing should work, however are you sure that the value has already been set at the time that you're trying to retrieve it?

Comment: No I don't think so. I updated the post with the code, where I handle it

Comment: you are setting a property on one object ("registration") but then pushing a different one ("controller")

Comment: The code was not properly formatted, so you probably didn't see the push of the registration. Is this even the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try something based on this :

```
SecondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
//Here you pass the data from the registerViewController to the secondViewController
controller.email = registration.email;

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(registration, true);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
  UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
  UIViewController ctrl = (UIViewController)board.InstantiateViewController("RegistrationViewController");
  ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
  this.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
```